# Using Membership on C# Library

Tags: c#, authentication, membership

I'm currently using a website that manages login by membership provider.
The trouble is that I need to also login on another application using the same credentials, which means I need to use Membership for that.
The application is a C++ OpenGl app that accesses the same webservice as the website does. 
Is there anyway to access membership in c# without using asp.net, in order to login in the OpenGl c++ app?

Comment: If you are asking about how to call webservice from C#.NET application then probably following link may help you: http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-consume-web-service-in-cnet.html

Comment: No, that I can do just fine. What I want to do is access membership functions such as those which can distinguish user roles and validate user passwords and login names and I want to do it in a C# Library that doesn't have anything to do with asp.net

Comment: @NunoNeto - All you have to do is provide the require code to connect the username and password.  This can be done with very little code.  Making a traditional desktop application access your database is simple enough.